# Was the financial crash of 2008 caused by top graduates of the American Ivy Leagues working at wall street banks?

Tags: economy, finance, 21st-century

From [this article](https://www.philstar.com/lifestyle/young-star/2013/03/15/919691/why-you-should-take-liberal-arts-course) by Lisandro 'Leloy' Claudio, a Philippine/a Filipino professor of history, politics, South & Southeast Asian Studies (and **not necessarily of finance, economics, mathematics or statistics**)

> a country can become a sad place if its most brilliant minds prioritize profit. In the 1990s and 2000s, most of the top graduates of the American Ivy League went to big Wall Street banks, and it was these geniuses who caused the financial crash of 2008. The world would have been better off if they had done something else.

**Question 1**: Was the financial crash of 2008 caused by top graduates of the American Ivy Leagues working at wall street banks?

**Question 2 and context**: Ok I'm gonna be explicit here to be clear at the cost of sounding, or even actually being, arrogant or ignorant. When I 1st read this like I was just about to start [grad school in mathematical finance/quantitative finance](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12729/do-quants-need-to-know-accounting). No offense or anything, but I actually kinda figured that the prof is not only wrong about this but has no idea what e is talking about. Does the quote make [substantial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantial_truth) sense?

Comment: From living through it, and paying attention to the news, it was true. I don't have any definitive sources though. Many people dislike Obama precisely because he didn't prosecute those who caused the financial crisis.

Comment: Are you looking for "but for" causation or proximate cause or just what? It's impossible to imagine that there wasn't at least one Ivy League graduate involved in some small way in causing it, but how much more Ivy League involvement is needed? 10% 50% 90% 100%?
It would help if you made it clear why you want to know. The quote sounds like pretty standard political criticism from the left and, like all partisan criticism, mixes relatively objective points with polemic.

Comment: "The world would have been better off if they had done something else." - The banks would still have been operating, what makes anyone think that things would have gone any differently with different people on the trading floors? People get jobs in these places because they like to gamble (with other people's money). I can't see how having less intelligent people in charge would have made things better.

Comment: Any thesis that posits a simple cause for a complex situation is flawed.  Any thesis which is built on establishing a class of mustache twirling villains is flawed.  People like simple solutions to complicated situations.  Solutions are a bit more difficult than finding people to blame.

Comment: You can read that quote in a couple different ways.   I would read "...better off if they had done something else" not as meaning that they caused the crash, just the more generic "society would be better off if smart people worked for the betterment of society rather than profit".

Comment: Given the scale, the most important strategic decisions (i.e. where are we putting our money) would be done at board level. I can't imagine that too many of the graduates from the 90s and 2000s would have reached the boards of the major players by 2008.

Comment: Also, notably, "top graduates of the American Ivy Leagues" doesn't necessarily mean "most brilliant minds."

Comment: Can we get a bit of a cleanup on this question? Its currently got what look to me to be 2 good answers (+ one from me). I'm inclined to think a lot of downvotes are because users think the quoted commentator was using a really bad argument, not because the question itself is a bad one. But if the question itself has problems, I'd like to see them fixed.

Comment: This question/answer is very relevant: "[what was the quant role in the 2008 crash?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/10345/what-was-the-quant-role-in-the-2008-crash)"

Comment: @T.E.D. 'Can we get a bit of a cleanup on this question?' but then 'if the question itself has problems' --> did you mean 'since' instead of 'if' i.e. it's indeed the case that the question itself does have problems?

Comment: @GorttheRobot thanks for sharing the link! shame on me that i have no idea what the answer is even though i have a master's degree in mathematical finance

Comment: @MarkOlson 'Are you looking for "but for" causation or proximate cause or just what? ' --> thanks for responding. hopefully clarified with question 2 and context. i think the guy has no idea what e is talking about. i disguise my arrogance in trying to ascertain this with the seemingly innocuous dumb question as to whether the aforementioned economic/financial crisis' is really simply caused by 'most of the top graduates of the American Ivy League went to big Wall Street banks, and it was these geniuses who caused the financial crash of 2008'.

Comment: @MCW lol amen to that. thanks!

Comment: @jeffronicus: Indeed, getting a degree in business from an Ivy League school (or anywhere else, FTM) does not require a brilliant mind.

Comment: I think the original statement in the article is very poorly formulated idea. Different practices by fresh graduates from certain business schools can be wrong / dangerous/ cause of a financial disaster, but responsibility is a much less clear cut concept. Morally, you can call the analysts responsible, the people who hire them, the people who bet money on them (investors betting on certain strategies), their bosses, who have no control over them, and so on. Who you blame is built on very subjective moral/political judgement, too, so in my opinion it is a poorly formed criticism.

Comment: @Greg thanks XD do you disagree that the prof has no idea what e is talking about?

Comment: Is this really a History question?

Comment: @Alex There's no 2 decade [requirement in this stackex site](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161/how-old-does-it-have-to-be-before-it-is-history) right?

Answer (score 9):

The author was mixing up cause and effect.

The position that the 2008 crash was largely caused by the behavior of lending institutions [is quite supportable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_crisis_of_2007%E2%80%932008#Causes). The [lending bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_housing_bubble) was pretty much indisputably the trigger for the crash. If not for the fortunate eventuality of the [head of the Fed at the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ben_Bernanke) having been the person who literally [wrote the book on the crash of 1929](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691118205), the results may well have been much more like the Great Depression than they ended up being.

Yes, it takes two to tango, and there were perhaps millions of individual borrowers out there happy to snap up that cheap credit lenders were offering. But borrowers are not necessarily expected to be financial experts, whereas lenders are. Its the lender's responsibility to verify that a rando off the street can pay off their loan, and that its properly secured in case they can't. Lenders were just flat out not doing their jobs.

Is it also a fact that many of these institutions were soaking up what one may consider the brightest young minds of that generation? That's much more debatable. However, there's certainly always going to be sharp young people who just want to train themselves to use their skills in whatever arena is currently hottest, and most likely to make them rich. In the early 2000's, lending was definitely where the action was. Was that a sign there was perhaps a problem there? Sure! Was it the cause? Probably more of an effect.

Its right to ask *why* lenders were suddenly acting that way. In fact, banks' bundling of loans into securities like they were doing *had been [explicitly made illegal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass%E2%80%93Steagall_legislation) in the wake of the 1929 crash*, as it was deemed to have been one of the causes of the crash back then as well. It had just been [re-legalized in 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramm%E2%80%93Leach%E2%80%93Bliley_Act) and took all of 9 years to crash the economy again.

Now let's ask, "Why was this behavior relegalized, if it was known to cause financial crashes?" This was part of the general attitude of "deregulation" brought into government in the wake of the [Reagan Revolution in 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaganomics#Policies), where lawmakers of his particular school of thought fought to reprioritize business convenience a bit more over whatever public safety those regulations were there to protect.

Comment: But why would the bundling of loans have been a problem, IF the underlying loans were sound?  OTOH, it seems as though the same amount in unbundled, unsound loans would have triggered a similar collapse.  Seems to me that the root of the problem was in the incentive (and ability) to make those unsound loans in the first place.  Just as (at least as I understand it) a primary cause of the '29 crash was brokerages allowing people to buy stocks on margin.  When a price drop triggered a margin call,  people had to sell, which triggered a cascade of further drops and calls.

Comment: @jamesqf - A bank that is restricted to lending has to make sure the underlying loans are sound, or they lose money. Its simple.  A bank that can also bundle loans together into a security has an incentive to make as many loans as possible, so they can sell more securities. That's an incentive that works directly **against** making sure all the loans are good. Bad loans can be (and routinely were) hidden by throwing them in with the good loans, and then of course selling the bundle to someone else. So now there's nobody in the "bank" who cares if the loans are good.

Comment: thanks. re 'you, or more likely the author' --> i have a master's in mathematical finance so what do you think? :| shooting the messenger much?

Comment: @BCLC - Yeah, I figured it wasn't you (or you wouldn't have thought this was weird enough to ask about). People surprise me sometimes though.

Comment: actually to also ask another thing. do you agree that the prof has no idea what e is talking about?

Comment: That's ... a bit harsh. I'd rather say he's got some good points that he expressed badly. I suspect the intention was just to rag on the supposed superiority of the Ivies a bit by pointing out the mass stupidity they engaged in during the bubble, and that's probably a decent point. I don't think it was his intention to propose a deep explanation for the financial crisis, just a deep explanation of why he's skeptical of people with business degrees.

Comment: (Its very surprising how much the tools of [critical source analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_criticism) can help one in everyday reading comprehension)

Comment: ...but in the general case, yeah you can't expect people to act contrary to their financial incentives (no matter where their degree is from). I don't have your Finance training, but my Econ101&102 courses were enough to learn that. Incentivizing crashing the economy, and then trying to put the inevitable result on greedy degrees (or on dumb greedy borrowers) misses the point. Hate the game, not the players.

Comment: T.E.D. damn you for being so empathic and giving the people the BOTD and applying the principle of charity...ok fine but w/rt the economic/financial crisis...assuming the intention was to propose a deep explanation...then the guy has no idea? i mean i know it's just a passing remark, so if you wanted to evaluate the whole article then you can just skip this remark maybe. but i'm not talking about the article of course. i'm really talking about what was supposed to be just a passing remark. P.S. you probably know more eco/fin than me in this regard. my major is maths, not eco/fin.

Comment: Well, looking it over, it appears to have been intended as an impassioned defense of a traditional Liberal Arts education. Its OK for that (although I've seen better. Its quite well-trod territory, and some of the practitioners are really good writers). Whatever the author's specialty in History is, I'm sure they are great at that. But I certainly wouldn't take them as an expert outside that realm. Is it a "bad" economic history analysis? Well, yeah, in the same way that a hammer is a bad screwdriver, or John 1 is bad astrophysics.

Comment: He appears to specialize in Asian history, particularly of the Philipines.

Comment: @T.E.D. right thanks. do you mean the Gospel according to John Chapter 1 from the Bible?

Answer (score 7):

During the crisis I worked in the team that was creating pricers for the complex derivatives in the bank where [CDSs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credit_default_swap) were invented.

2007-8 crisis has many reasons. The origin of it lies in easing the rules for lending in 1980s by a certain US president who wanted to win re-election. This enabled mortgage borrowing for so-called NINJA (no income, no job or assets) voters. At some point the real estate market got over-heated, making [subprime mortgages a toxic asset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subprime_mortgage_crisis), and then there was a domino effect.

Many parties are to blame for it. If you want a very careful detangling of all causes, to understand the role of politicians, regulators, rating agencies, banks obviously, and more, I recommend [Andrew Lo's (MIT) "Adaptive markets"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0691135142), chapter 9 (ca. 30 pages).

CDS on a name is equivalent to a portfolio of 2 bonds: buying a CDS on a name is like buying this name's bond and selling a riskless bond. There were some technical problems with CDSs (before the crisis they were traded at par, so the CDSs on the same name could not be offset). After the crisis, financial industries has solved this by setting up [a clearing system](https://www.theice.com/clear-europe/cds) and by changing the was CDSs are traded (fixed spread instead of trading at par). I wish other parties who are to blame for this crisis were acting as swiftly and efficiently…

If you look a bit further down in history, for cultural reasons of the 2007–8 crisis, you might want to watch [It's a Wonderful Life](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0038650/), a cult American Xmas movie (1946) that involves subprime lending and voluntary (!!!) bailing out of a banker by the general public. When one watches it in the context of 2007–8, it's jaw-dropping :)

Answer (score 6):

Fairly obviously not.  The problems of 2008 were the consequence of a great many people (far more than the total number of Ivy League graduates), all acting in ways that they thought would be profitable.  It was mostly not the actions themselves, but unforeseen interactions that led to problems.

Take for instance mortgage backed securities.  The people who invented them thought they had a good idea: bundle a bunch of mortgages, and you reduce the risk of one defaulting: https://www.thebalance.com/role-of-derivatives-in-creating-mortgage-crisis-3970477

Mortgage companies thought this was a good idea: we can bundle up our mortgages and sell them to securities companies, thus allowing us to lend more mortgages.  Since there weren't all that many people with good qualifications and 20% down payments out there, they had to relax the qualifications a bit.  But that's no problem: one or two defaults in a bundle surely aren't going to be a problem: after all, that's why those bundled securities were invented in the first place.  And so you got into a cycle where the end result was zero-doc, no down payment mortgages.

Potential homebuyers thought this was great: the economy's doing well, I can make the payments and get on the home appreciation ladder.  More people buying houses increases the price, via supply & demand.

That's fine, as long as folks still have the good jobs they had when they took out the mortgage.  The problem is what happens when the economy takes one of its periodic downturns, a bunch of people are out of jobs and can't make their mortgage payments.  You have a bunch of foreclosed houses, house prices drop, people get scared because they're underwater on the house and panic sell, prices drop still further, those securities become so much worthless paper, companies that hold a lot of that paper (expecting regular dividends from them) no longer have that cash flow and perhaps go bankrupt...

So it wasn't the fault of any one person or small group, but of the large-scale interactions between groups, each acting in perfectly reasonable ways as seen within their smaller compass.

Comment: thanks jamesqf! actually to also ask another thing. do you agree that the prof has no idea what e is talking about?

Comment: @BCLC Is your primary motivation here to determine the truth of the matter, or to prove that the professor is a bad person?

Comment: @BCLC:  IMHO he either has no idea what he's talking about, or he does know but is lying about it.  Or perhaps at some level he's lying to himself, because observation conflicts with the way he'd prefer things to be.  But I'm certainly no expert, and could perhaps be wrong.

Comment: It reads to me like a flippant bit of political rhetoric.   Political rhetoric always vastly oversimplifies to the point of being near pure bullshit.

Comment: @GorttheRobot never the person. always the action. shame vs guilt: [1](https://fs.blog/2014/10/brene-brown-guilt-shame/). [2](https://brenebrown.com/blog/2013/01/14/shame-v-guilt/). or that common saying like 'hate the sin; love the sinner'

Comment: thanks @GorttheRobot and jamesqf !

Comment: @GorttheRobot 'Is your primary motivation here to determine the truth of the matter, or to prove that the professor is a bad person?' --> no offense or anything but what do you care? i mean thanks for responding and all, but is my answer to your relevant to how would you would answer my question? or you're just curious?

Comment: Questions intended to "promote or discredit a specific idea, theory, cause, group or person" are specifically off-topic here.

Comment: I think this is a perfectly interesting question worth answers, but comments like this "do you agree that the prof has no idea what e is talking about?" are not going to be answered.   (Or at least shouldn't be.)   That's up to you to decide from the factual answers. :-P

Comment: @GorttheRobot hehehehe ok fine fine you win this round. thanks for explaining. i like how you said the word factual. check this out: [What is the opposite of argumentative?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-is-the-opposite-of-argumentative)

Answer (score 6):

What you referred to about "top graduates" was a "symptom," but not the underlying "disease."

The real problem was the "pedal to the medal," and "anything goes" mentality of the turn of the century. This was particularly true of the tech boom and bust, with financial products (e.g. "ninja" loans. So the Wall Street firms hired a disproportionate number of finance graduates, and the tech companies a disproportionate number of engineering graduates. A similar thing happened in the "roaring" 1920s, that ended with the 1929 crash.

I am the author of [A Modern Approach to Graham and Dodd Investing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003VIWZBA), a book published in 2004 that predicted a "1929" type crash in "2004-2006," that happened in 2008.

Comment: thanks Tom Au! actually to also ask another thing. do you agree that the prof has no idea what e is talking about?

Comment: 'What you referred to about ' --> shooting the messenger?

Comment: There were actually all kinds of people screaming about the lending bubble in the months leading up to the 2008 crash. I remember that vividly. However, nobody wanted to listen while there was all that seemingly free cash floating around (remember that vividly too).  Voting this up, because IMHO people who were publicly right despite the Emperor's New Clothes vibe going around deserve to be listened to.

Comment: I have vivid memories of someone on one of the news shows warning of impending collapse and literally being laughed off the program.

Comment: @GorttheRobot - One of the things I started noticing once the message started getting through was how every empty street corner with new construction ended up being a bank rather than a gas station or convenience store. You can still kind of tell when areas were developed in the early 2000's by how many banks are at nearby intersections.

Comment: [Here we go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1G0tfb8ZefA)

Answer (score 6):

I worked in the financial services industry back in 2007/8 in software engineering and saw the crash happen with a front row seat.

The root cause of the crash was the massive overvaluation of CDS (Credit Default Swap) instruments, combined with new software (created by the company I was working for) that enabled them to be traded in high volumes, combined with the mortgages that comprised those CDS instruments defaulting en masse.

Those mortgages had been the result of laws passed in the USA in the mid/late 1970s to make it easier for poor people to get mortgages. Problem was the buildings in question and the people that had gotten those mortgages didn't cover the mortgages and by the time they ran out exactly 30 years later (which is the standard duration of a mortgage) the buildings were worth less than the value of the mortgage and the people owning them didn't have the money to make up the rest, leaving the holders of the CDSs financially liable for massive payments to the lien holders (that's how CDSs work).

The result was that a few small financial institutions got into accute cash flow problems, leading to a massive selloff of their portfolios. This triggered automated trading systems to sell all stock in these institutions. This in turn triggered a massive selloff of stock in all financial institutions across the board. A snowball effect was achieved that had automated systems sell just about everything they could at whatever price they could get.

The blocks to prevent catastrophe after previous crashes had been changed from manual intervention (trading used to be stopped when certain drops in major indicators were reached until manually assumed) to automated systems, automated systems which happily assumed that the panic was no reason to stop the markets, effectively removing the blocks completely.

My job involved among other things visualising the value development of CDS instruments, and maintaining the predictive software that aided in their pricing. As such I (and the team I was part of) were some of the only people in the industry who knew anything about how these things worked (even most of the actual traders had no idea, all they knew was that they had been going up in price rapidly until then so must be a good deal).

That's the real story.

Comment: It would make sense to distinguish between "cause" and "reason/occasion/trigger"? As 'cause' is quite a bit more complex than just 'CDS' (by the way: that's what? While *I* might know the acro, but the A needs it spelled out), as you might see in TED's & jamesqf's As a few other 'causes'.

Comment: To put it more bluntly, there's a *reason* they were over-valued. I suspect for most market bubbles you'll find associated financial instruments were over-valued just before the burst.

Comment: thanks jwenting! actually to also ask another thing. do you disagree that the prof has no idea what e is talking about?

Comment: Could you please spell out CDS on first use? That abbreviation means many things in the financial world.

Comment: @CareyGregory sorry, for the people involved it is well known to mean Credit Default Swap

Comment: The explanation of "mortgages given in the 70s to poor people were ending" is just nonsense. If those people did not pay they would have been foreclosured when they did stop paying. In fact, 30 years later they would have paid almost all of the loan and, no matter how devaluated(citation needed for the devaluation) those properties were, their value would have been enough for refinancing. And if not refinanced, the loss would have been minimal. This seems like a totally made up argument.

Comment: @SJuan76 nope, that's exactly what happened. They were mortgages that were granted based on the value of the property alone, no monthly payment needed until after the expiry date at which point the entire amount becomes due for payment (with the property as collateral). Guess what, the tenants didn't have the money to pay, and the property had deteriorated to way below the value as well (if it ever had that value, the market had become inflated because of those mortgage products). Apparently you've little understanding of how the mortgage market works.